# How can I use the KeyDown event with the exception of backspace?

Tags: javascript

I have a file with multiple inputs. I have a Javascript function which writes information about the input and I do not want it triggered when the user is pressing backspace.

EDIT: Question: Why does this code not work in terms of preventing backspace execution? Instead the entire function does not work:

```
                function hide_words(z,x)
            {
                     if(event.key == 8)
                     {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     }
                        document.getElementById(z).innerHTML = x; 
            }
```

The above just stops the functioning from executing all together.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`, would be your answer.

Comment: Have you tried event.key = 46?

Comment: Hmmm, no code given thus far has worked, only have either stopped the entire function or didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Update this to:

```js
 function inputOn(event)
 {

    if(event.keyCode == 8)
    {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
   
  }

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", inputOn, false);
```

```html
<input id="input" style="width: 400px;" value="try to delete any text using backspace." />
```

`preventDefault` will cancel out the normal action. So the backspace won't do a thing. A `keyDown` is cancelable, so this works. Please note that the input of other keys is still possible.

You might also want to catch `keyCode` `46` which is the delete button.

Comment: This only stops any key from triggering the function. Problem is still occuring

Comment: See edit, it shouldn't stop the execution of other keys.